# AspectJ is not working on beans without interface and defined in the configuration class

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-aop

I created a demo application to reproduce it:

**DemoService**

```kotlin
open class DemoService {
    fun test() {
        println("test function is executed.")
    }
}
```

**DemoAspect**

```kotlin
@Aspect
class DemoAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.example.demo.service.DemoService.test(..))")
    fun testAspect(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint) {
        println("before test function.")
        joinPoint.proceed()
        println("after test function.")
    }
}
```

**AppConfig**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    fun demoService() = DemoService()

    @Bean
    fun demoAspect() = DemoAspect()
}
```

**SpringDemoApplication**

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AppConfig::class)
class SpringDemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val context = runApplication<SpringDemoApplication>(*args)
    val demoService = context.beanFactory.getBean(DemoService::class.java)
    demoService.test()
}
```

Execution result:

```
test function is executed.
```

The aspect is not working which is not expected.

I tried following variations and they worked correctly:

#### Remove the beans in configuration services and register beans by annotations

**DemoService**

```kotlin
@Service
open class DemoService {
   ...
}
```

**AppConfig**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    fun demoAspect() = DemoAspect()
}
```

#### Let `DemoService` implements an interface

**DemoService**

```kotlin
interface DemoService {
    fun test()
}

open class DemoServiceImpl: DemoService {
    override fun test() {
        println("test function is executed.")
    }
}
```

**AppConfig**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    fun demoService() = DemoServiceImpl()

    @Bean
    fun demoAspect() = DemoAspect()
}
```

I want to understand why the AspectJ is not working on this combination:

1. The target bean is not implementing any interface.
2. The bean is registered in Configuration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP, in contrast to native AspectJ, is based on dynamic proxies. In order to proxy a class, it must not be `final`. In Kotlin terms, it must be `open`. Moreover, in order to proxy a method, it must not be `final` either, i.e. you also need to `open` the method. See also [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/open-keyword#overriding-methods-and-properties).

So, please use `open fun test()`, then it works as expected.

---

**Update for follow-up question:**

> why it works if I use @Service even though the function is final?

Because probably in your build you use the Kotlin [all-open compiler plugin with Spring support enabled](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support). If I were you, I would not use `@Bean` factory methods anyway, but simply `@Component`,  `@Service` or similar Spring annotations directly on the implementation classes.

Of course, you could also use the generic all-open plugin in addition to the Spring version and then do this:

```kotlin
annotation class OpenMe()
```

```kotlin
@OpenMe
class DemoService {
  fun test() {
    println("test function is executed.")
  }
}
```

Then, in Maven you would do something like:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <args>
      <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
    </args>
    <compilerPlugins>
      <plugin>all-open</plugin>
      <plugin>spring</plugin>
    </compilerPlugins>
    <pluginOptions>
      <option>all-open:annotation=org.acme.OpenMe</option>
    </pluginOptions>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Then you would not need any `open` keywords on the service class or method anymore and could continue to use your `@Bean` factory method. But I think this is more complicated than using Spring annotations - convention over configuration.

Comment: It works, thanks!

Further question: why it works if I use `@Service` even though the function is final?